# How can i draw a circle with a circle

Tags: android

How can i do that? Is there an example for that? Can you show me ?

For ex. I have an circle like that

```
RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(0, 0, 40, new int[]{Color.RED, Color.YELLOW}, new float[] {1,0}, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint2.setShader(gradient);
canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2, 40, paint2);
```

How this circle can draw a circle?

Comment: You're going to have to explain the question a little better. Do you want to draw a circle INSIDE that circle?

Comment: yeah exactly this is. But the circle which draw a new circle must be smaller than other.(which is drawn) Above circle is drawer circle and it will smaller than new circle which will be drawing by it

Comment: This should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992094/how-to-draw-a-smaller-shapedrawable-inside-another-shapedrawable-programmaticall