# how stretch inside a circle image with nine patch

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a image that is as a circle .I want stretch only part of inside of it and i dont want stretch borders of it.
as example my image is same below

[image]

I set it as backgrount my textview.i want if text is large it stretch as a circle and text place in center black circle .

Comment: so you want the inner dot to shrink/grow and the outer circle to shrink/grow with the same border width?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to do that with a nine patch drawable. You should consider using a ring gradient instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be possible with using the 9-patch images. However I think your requirement can be achieved  by using shape drawables. Following are the sample code which you can refer:

1. Create two circular shapes (outer_circle.xml and inner_circle.xml) in drawable folder.
2. Place the textview inside a LinearLayout where layout background is outer circle and text background is inner circle.
3. Programmatically update the height of textview to make it equal with the width.

Following is the code:

1. outer_circle.xml

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="#000000" />

<size
    android:height="120dp"
    android:width="120dp" />
```

2.inner_circle.xml

```
<!-- Give the padding so the text does not touches the edge of inner circle -->
<padding
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp" />

<solid android:color="#000000" />
```

3.Layout Sample

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/outer_circle"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/inner_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

4.Set the textView layout programmatically

```
// Override this method to get the text width dynamically and 
// apply the same height to the textview
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    TextView tvTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTest);
    int tvWidth = tvTest.getWidth();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tvLayout = tvTest.getLayoutParams();
    tvLayout.height = tvLayout.width = tvWidth;
    tvTest.setLayoutParams(tvLayout);

}
```

Following is the part of screenshot

[image]

Alternatively you can have a look into this links

[How to draw a smaller ShapeDrawable inside another shapeDrawable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992094/how-to-draw-a-smaller-shapedrawable-inside-another-shapedrawable-programmaticall)

Hope this will be useful.